# Get the size of longest sublist from a list in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I would like to get the size of the longest sublist from a list.

for example

(getlongest ((a) b (d e m n) (a d (c m g c y u m l d ) a) ))

returns 9 since (c m g c y u m l d ) has size 9.

I wrote this function

```
(define getlongest
  (lambda (ls)
    (cond 
     ((null? ls)0)
     (else
      (cond
        ((atom? (car ls))
       (+ 1 (getlongest (cdr ls))))
         (else
          (max (getlongest(car ls)) (getlongest(cdr ls)))))))))
```

However if I write

`(getlongest ((a) (a (d d d e) m)))`

i get 5. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The reason is pretty obvious if you trace through the program with pen and paper. I suggest you do that, and update the question with your findings. Hints: 1. Think about how lists are formed, under the covers. 2. `(+ 1 (getlongest (cdr ls)))` does not do what you expect, given the way that `getlongest` is defined.

Comment: I know there are many people who post homework so that other people can solve it for them. In my case, I am a beginner at this and it took me a couple of hours to come up with this erroneous solution. If I posted the question was because I was desperate to find a solution. I have go thru several iteration of paper tracing and I know there is something wrong, but I just don't know how to fix it. I am trying to improve my skill at this but I don't have many options. I will go thru one more round of paper tracing and see if i find something new.

Comment: In that case, use mquander's answer as a starting point. :-) If you like, trace through their version and see how it differs from yours; though, mquander's answer already explains in detail where the difference is.

Comment: The important part is thinking about what happens in the list in this circumstance:  A list has an atom in the first position, and maybe in the second position, so you add 1, 2, and then you see that there's a sub-list in the third position.  That's where your code does the wrong thing, because it doesn't distinguish between the case that the sub-list is longest (in which case the 2 doesn't count toward the total) and the case that the sub-list is not longest (in which case the 2 counts.)

Comment: Ok, I found what you were suggesting. Atoms which are not part of a sublist are counted as part of the sublist. For example `(getlongest (a (b c d))` returns 4.

Comment: Although the comments were very good and the points made by Chris and mquander were great I still haven't been able to solve this! Any body that could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with your code is that you're counting 1 length for the part of a list you've already counted, even if you go on to find that a sub-list of that list is actually the longest.  For example, your code returns 5 for this case, too:  `(getlongest '(a (b (c (d (e))))))`.

Your approach is sort of hard to fix easily. You'll need to pass more data down when you recurse, I think; if each call to `getlongest` knew the current length, then you should be able to get the right maximum.

If this isn't homework, here's how I would instinctively write the same function (not as efficient as possible, but simple:)

```
(define (get-longest x)
  (cond ((null? x) 0)
        ((atom? x) 1)
        ; else take either the length of this list, or of the longest sub-list
        (else (apply max (length x) (map get-longest x)))))
```

Comment: How does "homework" imply "not suppposed to use higher-order functions"? I'd like to think a _good_ course on FP would want to encourage as much HOF as possible.

Comment: Also, you can simplify the `apply` invocation thusly: `(apply max (length x) (map get-longest x))`. I find that the extra `cons` makes the code harder to read.

Comment: I assumed that this simple problem being homework probably means it fits into a "how to think about simple problems recursively" section, in which case the point of the exercise is figuring out how to structure the recursive solution, but I took out my disclaimer anyway.  Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot momentarily that `apply` did that.

Comment: Can anyone else help me with this? I cannot figure it out yet. I only need someone to help me solve this one. It would help me to solve other problems. How can I fix my problem.

Comment: One way that you could do this without `map` or `apply` is by "unrolling" the map.  That is, you could say that the longest length of a list is the max of its length, the longest length of the `car`, and the longest length of the `cdr`, and by recursing down the list you could eventually examine the length of each sub-element in this fashion.